# Can a DOG learn to cover it's feces?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, toilet-training

I'm wondering what other ways can we teach a dog to deal with it's feces. Can dogs learn to cover their feces? Is it even natural for them? And why don't usual dogs cover their feces? Is it a territory thing? Are they not afraid of bigger animals to find them, or is it just that they don't care or think it doesn't make a reason for other animals to come look for them?

It would be really great if someone is able to explain to me the whole thing, because a friend of mine is thinking of adopting a puppy but she's afraid the dog would dirty up her home which can make family problems for her. She is thinking of having a sand box in her yard and let the dog do it's buisiness in there like a CAT.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, a dog will not go like a cat. I do believe it can be territorial, but it is also part of the dog personality. I highly doubt a dog could be taught to go like a cat. It could be worth a shot, but don't be surprised if the dog doesn't get it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I think, but I also know that dogs do whatever they are trained to do. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option, may aunt does this at her house for her little Lhasa Apso.
She doesn't have much grass in her back yard so she made a box filled with [large white gravel](http://cdn.frooition.com/110156/images/XF10201C-MK2.jpg) which her dog uses as a toilet. Feces should be picked up as they happen and you can wash the gravel with a hose and soapy water.

It's really easy to train a dog to go in a specific area, especially if it's unique looking. Essentially all you need to do is bring the dog directly to the box and as soon as he/she does her business you give treats and praise.

[It looks kind of like this, minus the fire hydrant.](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/1f/b7/88/1fb788d0e274bbe80885454bbeec5dbc--landscape-fabric-fabric-covered.jpg)

Comment: Yes @Rebecca RVT that's what my friend is thinking of thanks for your feedback.